# BeautifulSoup get_text separate values with "<br>"

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

HTML:

```
"<td class='tdtl'><a class='col' href='detail.php?id=1' target='_blank''>List 1< br>detail 1</a></td>"
"<td class='tdtl'><a class='col' href='detail.php?id=2' target='_blank''>List 2< br>detail 2</a></td>"
"<td class='tdtl'><a class='col' href='detail.php?id=3' target='_blank''>List 3< br>detail 3</a></td>"
"<td class='tdtl'><a class='col' href='detail.php?id=4' target='_blank''>List 4< br>detail 4</a></td>"
"<td class='tdtl'><a class='col' href='detail.php?id=5' target='_blank''>List 5< br>detail 5</a></td>"
```

Python coding:

```
for index in soup.select("col"):
    print(index.get_text())
```

RESULT:

> Line 1detail 1
>
> Line 2detail 2
>
> Line 3detail 3
>
> Line 4detail 4
>
> Line 5detail 5

How to retrieve "Line 1" and "detail 1" in variables?

Comment: Are you sure your `<br>` looks like `< br>` in the `HTML`?

Comment: Post HTML code, but I can’t see the "<br>" tag on my question. Therefore, adding a spare is only for display.

Comment: The initial HTML is missing the </a> tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the tag is always formatted as `< br>` then you can use a simple split :

```
the_lists = []
the_details = []

for index in soup.select("a.col"):
    my_text = index.get_text().split('< br>')
    the_lists.append(my_text[0])
    the_details.append(my_text[1])
    
print(the_lists) # ['List 1', 'List 2', 'List 3', 'List 4', 'List 5'] 
print(the_details) # ['detail 1', 'detail 2', 'detail 3', 'detail 4', 'detail 5']
```

---

**EDIT**

To manage other format of `<br>` tag such as `< br>` `<br>` `<br >` you can use regex :

```
the_lists = []
the_details = []

for index in soup.select("a.col"):
    text = re.sub("<(\s*)br(\s*)>","<br>",index.get_text())
    my_text = text.split('<br>')
    the_lists.append(my_text[0])
    the_details.append(my_text[1])
    
print(the_lists)    
print(the_details)
```

Comment: "<br>" with spaces is working, but "<br>" without spaces cannot be split.

Comment: In your example, you did not have <br> but only < br>. However you can manage it with regex. see update